# I want to store a 2d Char array into an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

First of all, I have checked previous posts and still could not find an answer. So here is my question: I want to store a 2d char array showing a specific state of a chess board (for example the starting state) into an `ArrayList`. An example of a state would be:

[image: ChessState]

How would I store this state (being a 2d char array called chessBoard) into an `ArrayList` called chessState?

The names do not matter but I thought it would help to provide any help you can.

My previous attempts have gotten me "C@22e7c30e" in my output.

Thank you for any help offered!

Comment: You should show some code.  If your problem is just related to printing, `Arrarys.deepToString()` will print the contents of an array.

Comment: I didn't think showing code would help, plus i wouldn't know what code to show. I can add the method on setting up my 2d array to look like the starting state of a chessboard but i didn't think that would help in finding an answer.

Comment: The string you have provided, C@22etc, is how Java prints arrays by default.  It's not wrong.  You're missing something and some code would help.

Comment: @jordan *"I didn't think showing code would help,"* no code does not help either... *"plus i wouldn't know what code to show."* the code that *declares*, *initializes* and *prints* the array, and if the type of the array is a class that its definition too. At best you create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: i figured it out, thank you @markspace for mentioning how the array is printing, since I am new to this i appreciate the way you asked for additional information. I haven't used this very much. Anyway to fix this, I was correct with how i stored the array, but not how i displayed it.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle hey friend I think you may have posted something incorrect. My question wasn't asking how I ask a question in stack overflow :) i don't know where you read that, anyway its alright I figured out the answer!

Comment: @jordan Timothy was trying to guide you to improve your question to make it more answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a class **ChessState** containing the 2D Char Array and then make a an arraylist of those states?

```
public class ChessState {
...
}



public class Chess {
...

ArrayList<ChessState> = ...

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<char[][]> ChessState= new ArrayList<char[][]>();
ChessState.add(chessBoard);
```

Generally you can put whatever you like in an array . If you want more information about the chessboard do it with an object. The code above should work for a 2d char array.

Answer (score 0):

```
public char[][] possibleChessMove = new char[8][8];

ArrayList<char[][]> storeMoves = new ArrayList<>();
```

and after filling the possibleChessMove to the starting board state I did this:

```
 storeMoves.add(possibleChessMove);

                        for (int i=0;i<storeMoves.size();i++ ) {
                            for (int j=0;j<8;j++) {
                                for (int k=0;k<8;k++) {
                                    System.out.print(storeMoves.get(i)[j][k]+" ");

                                }
                                System.out.println("");
                            }
                            System.out.println("\n\n\n");
                        }
```

Originally the question I asked was how do I store them, because I did think I was storing them wrong. But in the end the way I was printing it was incorrect.